# Ошибка установки Laravel 8 OpenServer curl error 60

Tags: laravel, composer, openserver, установка

Пытаюсь установить laravel 8 на OpenServer(PHP 7.4) через Composer
(Стоит последняя версия Composer 2.0.8)
До этого стояла более старая версия laravel, удалил её, чтобы поставить новую.
Находясь в `c:\openserver` ввожу команду `composer global require laravel/installer` в терминал OpenServer.
(Если вводить `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app` ,то тоже выводит ошибки)
Сперва установка идёт нормально, затем выводится такое сообщение:

```
Failed to download symfony/console from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/symfony/console/legacy.zip/12e071278e396cc3e1c149857337e9e192deca0b: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
    Now trying to download from source
 1/3 [=========>------------------]  33%    Failed to download symfony/filesystem from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/symfony/filesystem/legacy.zip/d99fbef7e0f69bf162ae6131b31132fa3cc4bcbe: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
    Now trying to download from source
 2/3 [==================>---------]  66%    Failed to download symfony/process from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/symfony/process/legacy.zip/075316ff72233ce3d04a9743414292e834f2cb4a: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.4.18): Cloning 075316ff72
    Install of symfony/process failed
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.4.18): Cloning d99fbef7e0
    Install of symfony/filesystem failed
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.4.18): Cloning 12e071278e
    Install of symfony/console failed
    0 [>---------------------------]
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/process.git, git was not found, check that it is instal
  led and in your PATH env.

  'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Пробовал установить более старую версию, которая была раньше, тоже ошибка.
Насколько я вижу, Composer пишет что-то про Git, однако для установки Laravel ведь он не нужен ?
По крайней мере на оф. сайте про это нигде не сказано, и в туториалах такого нет.
Или я что-то не так понимаю ?

Comment: у Вас composer не смог скачать напрямую, из-за проблем с сертификатом, и решил пробовать клонировать, но git тоже не нашел

Comment: @evgenii-izhboldin, а какие могут быть проблемы с сертификатом ? Где вообще он находится ? Что можно почитать про это ? Почему раньше проблем с ним не было ? Переустановка OpenServer может помочь ? Вообще не разбираюсь в этом вопросе, если можете, дайте какие-нибудь наводки.

Comment: с опен сервером я не работал очень давно, ошибка похоже на то что в php неверные конфиг для curl, (видел старые темы: https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2170), либо может еще какая то проблема, собственно с опен сервера давно ушел на использование чистой виртуалки с ubuntu + php + nginx, как раз из-за переодических таких вот внезаных проблем на ровном месте (много конфигов там, зависимости которых иногда неочевидны)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён, разобрался сам. На компьютере был вирус, после его удаления всё заработало.